# svg file not rendering properly in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg

I can't figure out why Chrome won't completely render this image while all other browsers can. https://www.c2-it.com/test/logo-test.html
The strange this is that if you open the image itself directly in Chrome it displays properly.

Comment: There's a typo in your data URL: replace `data:img/png;` with `data:image/png;`

Comment: Where are you seeing that?

Comment: Check your svg file: it contains an image with an dataURL. Just open the svg in a code editor and fix this.